# Proper way of working with .txt-files in object-orientated programming

Tags: vb.net, file, shared, object-oriented-analysis

The program I am working on works with several different .txt-files to store its data. Let's just say our file looks like this:

```
a1; b1; c1; 
a2; b2; c2; 
...
```

To work with such a file I made a class, let's say it is called CFile. Now I wrote function to get each of the vectors a,b and c. They work something like this:

```
Public Shared Function getAFromFile() As List(Of Double)
        Dim datei As New FileStream(filePathSelectedInForm, FileMode.Open)
        Dim leser As New StreamReader(datei)
        Dim zeile As String
        Dim werte() As String

        Dim a As New List(Of Double)
        Dim b As New List(Of Double)
        Dim c As New List(Of Double)
        While leser.Peek <> -1
            zeile = leser.ReadLine
            werte = zeile.Split(";")
            a.Add(werte(0))
            b.Add(werte(1))
            c.Add(werte(2))
        End While

        leser.Close()
        datei.Close()

        getAFromFile = a
    End Function
```

Of course I want to calculate something with the data now. Let's say I want to multiply each Double with a Double of another file called x and then add another value called r. So I generate another function in my class something like this:

```
   Public Shared Function calculateWithA(r as Double) As List(Of Double)
        dim a as List(Of Double) = getAFromFile()
        dim x as List(Of Double) = getXFromFile()
        Dim result As New List(Of Double)
        For i = 0 To a.Count - 1
            result.Add(a.Item(i) * x.Item(i) + r)
        Next
        calculateWithA = result  
   End Function
```

Let's say we have a datagridview on a form and it is filled with our vectors a, b and c. So we have 3 columns and an undefined number of rows, depending on the amount of elements of a, b and c from the textfile.
Now I add a 4th row in which I want to store the calculated values. The proper way is to open my file, get the vector a, open the other file, get the vector x, multiply them, add r and then write it in the datagridview.

Now imagine r is the index of the datagridview-row. I now need a loop from r=0 to 'amount of rows-1' and call calculateWithA(r). Everytime the function is called the functions getAFromFile() and getXFromFile() are called in it two. I assume that opening a file is pretty slow, that's why I think it would be better to make a and x public shared List(Of Double) and just get them once and then work with them in the function calculateWithA. Something like this:

```
 Private Shared a As New List(Of Double)
 Private Shared x As New List(Of Double)

 Public Shared sub getAandX()
            a  = getAFromFile()
            x  = getXFromFile()
            Dim result As New List(Of Double)
            For i = 0 To a.Count - 1
                result.Add(a.Item(i) * x.Item(i) + r)
            Next
 End Sub

 Public Shared Function calculateWithA(r as Double) As List(Of Double)
            Dim result As New List(Of Double)
            For i = 0 To a.Count - 1
                result.Add(a.Item(i) * x.Item(i) + r)
            Next
            calculateWithA = result  
       End Function
```

In this case I can call calculateWithA(r) several times while the performance-intensive functions working with the file are just called once. But I HAVE TO call getAandX() before using calculateWithA(r) or I will get an error or work with old values of a and x. And that's where my problem is:
I want my program to be as much modular as possible and follow the rules of an object-oriented program. But if I have to call a function to be sure another function works, that's against those rules, right? But if I work with my modular version, calling each file everytime I call the function, I get a pretty bad performance and a long waiting-time.
What do you guys say? Which way should I go or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In this case i guess you should call getAandX from calculateWithA such that you first check if lists are empty or not. If they are empty call getAandX and then run the loop to get results. After loop clear the lists a and x as those are not useful anymore.
Now every time you call calculateWithA it will first freshen up data and then process it.
This way, file IO oprration will happen once and the responsibility of loading data will be of calculateWithA function.

Comment: But in this case I HAVE TO clear the lists after the loop. If I forget this, it won't work next time. So again I have to call function to make sure another function works right. Just instead of calling the function before the loop, I have to call a function right after the loop. I think hat's not object-oriented.